# Why are past tense verbs used as imperative at times ("пошел вон", "пошли пообедаем")?

Tags: глаголы

Most of the examples I can think of are imperatives used in an angry tone ("Пошел вон!", "Упал, отжался!") and it seems the past tense is used just to underline that there's no alternative to the action suggested/ordered. The person speaking is so sure their orders will be followed, they talk as if it already happened.

However, "пошли" is often a friendly suggestion that doesn't come with a lot of authority. Is there a better explanation for this?

Comment: These may actually be past subjunctive rather than past (simple).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Long story short: Russian verb's features like aspect, tense, mood and voice cannot be always determined through morphological analysis. It's the feature characteristic of Russian verb.

---

Most Russian grammatists criticize traditional morphological approach to tense / aspect / mood / voice analysis of Russian verbs.

For instance, all three traditional tenses and infinitive can be used as imperatives, varying the mood nuances:

> - Да пошёл ты к дьяволу со своими гландами! ― рассердилась Нюра. *[Василий Шукшин. Печки-лавочки (1970-1972)]*
> - ― Значит, так, сейчас ты встаешь и любой ценой прекращаешь эту кутерьму. *[Михаил Козаков. Актерская книга (1978-1995)]*
> - Возьмёшь с собой пару или тройку рабочих с лопатами! *[Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 1 (1978)]*
> - ― Встать, учитель идёт! ― приказали дети, и Лагарпов послушно встал. *[Алексей Слаповский. Жизнь Лагарпова (1999)]*

and the (morphological) imperative itself can be used, say, as optative:

> - ― Лопни мои глаза, Камилла, если я спал! *[Роберт Штильмарк. Наследник из Калькутты (1950-1951)]*

or subjunctive:

> - Повой она ещё каких-нибудь минут пять, и Серый схватил бы её. *[М. М. Пришвин. Кладовая солнца (1945)]*

As you noted, contrasting sg. past and the pl. past distinguishes imperative from hortative.

Thus, formal morphology does not unequivocally define the actual verb features. As @shabunc noted, this is called transposition.

Vinogradov in *Русский язык* writes:

> Таким образом, в грамматической традиции чаще всего речь идет не столько о языковых формах глагольного времени и их значениях, сколько о психологических планах времени, об абстрактных линиях и точках времени3 . Система живых форм времени русского глагола в их основных значениях и в их сложном грамматическом взаимоотношении с другими глагольными формами почти никем из русских лингвистов последнего времени (кроме акад. А. А. Шахматова) не осмыслялась. На этой почве складывается убеждение: время русского глагола психологично и субъективно. Оно не вполне "грамматикализовано". Оно определяется больше психологически, чем грамматически.
>
> Учение современной грамматики о формах времени русского глагола является отчасти бледным и искаженным видоизменением старой теории "вневременности" русского глагола, отчасти воспроизведением упрощенных грамматических схем русского глагола, предназначавшихся для иностранцев и возникших еще в XVII в.

Russian verb is subject to develop it much more readily than the other parts of speech. For instnance, Chukovsky in *Живой как жизнь* writes:

> Или эта форма: «я пошел» вместо «я ухожу». Человек еще сидит за столом, он только собирается уйти, но изображает свой будущий поступок уже совершенным.
>
> С этим я долго не мог примириться.

and also Vinogradov, *ibid*:

> Значение 2-го лица в форме повелительного наклонения определяется лишь интонацией и отсутствием указаний на иное действующее лицо. Между тем эта форма может сочетаться и с существительными в качестве субъектов действия, получая значение 3-го лица, и может употребляться в неопределенно-личном значении. Известно, что до 20 — 30-х годов XIX в. в русском литературном языке способность этой формы относиться к 3-му лицу была гораздо активнее и шире. В современном языке употребление этой формы в значении 3-го лица живо, хотя и непродуктивно.
>
> - Спи, кто может, я спать не могу. *(Некрасов)*
> - Ах! тот скажи любви конец, // Кто на три года вдаль уедет. *(Грибоедов, "Горе от ума")*

which means that developing and losing verb forms may be a matter of decades in Russian.

Russian has developed a hortative form by adding the pl. imp. ending *-те* to I. sg. present:

> - Пойдёмте и поговорим за бутылкой доброго вина. [А. Н. Толстой. Черная пятница (1924)]

Currently, it's only considered grammatical for verbs derived from *-идти, -ехать, -быть*, however, this form is developing and most probably will soon make it into literary language.

Comment: Wonderful answer! I am trying to rationalise this "past imperative": I perceive it as a quite rude order, it sort of implies and imposes finality over your future action. I think a similar feeling is (more jokingly) conveyed by "I want it done by yesterday!". You sort of have no other option than to will have done what is demanded from you. (And, also cursing! `Пошел нах**!` is exactly this form, even though old-stylish "Ах, оставьте меня!" is it too.)

Answer (score 0):

First, present tense also can be used as imperative, for example "быстро уходим!".

Second, usage of certain forms as some another forms (in a very wide sense - semantical, syntactical, grammatical etc.)  is called [transposition](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%28%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%29).
Wikipedia claims that there are 12 different types of transposition in Russian, but I'm not sure how, regarding this classification, it is called exactly this one, but actually I've seen in literature term `прошедшее время в директивном употреблении`.

As far as I know, this is property of some verbs which are used for designation of motivation of joint actions (`пошли`, `побежали`, `поплыли`). I guess it is quite obvious how this forms became imperative, at least for usage with plural pronouns.
"А поплыли туда, друзья, к той скале" => "Эй, поплыли туда!".

Comment: Doesn't "А поплыли туда, друзья, к той скале" already use "поплыли" as an imperative?

Comment: @ruskie.info, it does, but imperative forms can slightly vary, and first form is somewhat closer to "А давайте поплывём" - motivation instead of order.

Comment: @shabunc: this mood (motivation instead of order) is called hortative.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, all right about ПОШЛИ - this friendly offer. Even as one can say "вон смотри они пошли в банк" или "она пошла домой"
Clerk about the tone in the past tense - it can tell a man who believes himself to higher position or more companion. Such orders in the army or in the courtyard outside. But this is against the rules of the Russian language!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

well, in the expression "пошли домой" - "пошли" is rather ungrammatical colloquial alternative to a grammatically correct "пойдем домой" than a typical example of a past tense used as an imperative.

Comment: Could you please specify what do you mean when you you say "ungrammatical"?